# How do I make custom grass using particles?

Tags: objects, particles

I've looked everywhere and all I can find is how to make realistic grass using hair particles. What I'm trying to do is create a sort of low poly scene using grass that I modelled myself. I put it into the particle system, but it's all just lying on it's side even though the Initial Orientation is set to Object Z, in fact, non of the orientation settings will make the grass go right side up. The grass models that the particles are referencing are right side up. Some of them are even floating in the air.

How do I make them face right side up? How do I stop them from floating? It would also be good to have them be angled towards the direction that the ground faces are facing.

**EDIT**

Okay, I figured out how to get them the right direction... sort of. However, now they are appearing on the wrong side of the mesh. I checked the Normals and they are the right direction, and when I flip them to the wrong direction, the grass appears on top, but upside down.

[image: Normals Correct]

[image: Normals Wrong]

Answer (score 1):

Well after hours of looking things up and getting frustrated, I realised that the origin points of the grass were set to the top and not the bottom. Problem solved!