# How to rotate particle group upwards?

Tags: mesh, particles, weight-painting

I'm making a field for my demo, but I ran into a problem. I made a clump of grass for the ground and turned it into a group, then selected my ground and added a particle system. The grass looks okay, but its on the wrong side of the plane. I used the built-in rotation feature for the particle system, but when I set it to global x, y or z, the grass just lays on its side or flips upside down. Is there another way to rotate the grass? Also, I weight painted most of the plane and added lots of weight near the center.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72448/how-do-i-make-custom-grass-using-particles

Comment: Have you tried flipping the normals of your plane?  Quick fix if it works.